# String formating and store the values

Tags: string, formatting, string-formatting

I have a string similar to below
**"OPR_NAME:CODE=value,:DESC=value,:NUMBER=value,:INITIATOR=value,:RESP"**

I am using StringTokenizer to split the string into tokens based on the delimiter(,:),I need the values of
CODE,DESC and NUMBER.
Can someone pls tell how to achieve this ? The values may come in random order in my string 
For eg my string may be like below as well :
**"OPR_NAME:DESC=value,:NUMBER=value,:CODE=value,:INITIATOR=value,:RESP"** and still it should be able to fetch the values.

I did below to split the string into tokens

```
StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(str,",:");
        while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {            
             System.out.println(st.nextToken());             
         }
```

But not sure how to store these tokens to just get the value of 3 fields as mentioned above.

Thanks !!

Comment: Use a regular expression like "[^=]+$" or easier substring what is after the "=" symbol

Comment: can you pls elaborate a little bit

Answer (score 0):

Okay so what I meant is, detect where is the "=" and then apply a substring to get the value you want.

rough example

```
System.out.println(st.nextToken().substring(st.nextToken().indexOf('=')+1,st.nextToken().length()));
```

Use split instead :

```
String[] parts = X.split(",:");
for (String x:parts) {
    System.out.println(x.substring(x.indexOf('=')+1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the length of the value is not fixed so not sure if I can apply substring in this case.

Comment: Yea, the length isn't fixed . Basically what I wrote should bring you everything after the "=" for each token, give it a try

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 20
 at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
 at com.test.socket.StringFormat.main(StringFormat.java:35)

Comment: Also mate,I don't need the value of all the tokens I just need the value for 3 fields,which may come in random order in the string.